# MySQL Workbench: Generate a bunch of rows?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL workbench model that I've used to generate a schema. To play around with it, I'd like a bunch of fake data. Is there an easy way to generate this, or must I do it by hand?

Answer (score 9):

This is a site I always use to generate dummy data.  http://www.generatedata.com  This will generate the data as well as the insert scripts.

Comment: Good point.  A hastle, but manageable solution would be in your foreign key column, use the number range in the data type column with the max number being the biggest key in your related table.  This comes with a few drawbacks such as only being able to reliably use a freshly generated (full set) of data.  This also assumes your keys are always numbers.

Comment: Well, fortunately for me in playing with this data I'm only reading it, not altering it in any way. So perhaps the lack of foreign keys isn't a huge issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with mysql workbench

## schema for table newtable

```
create table newtable (c1 int, c2 varchar(255),create_ts timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, update_ts timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

## on a shell created this file foo.txt

```
for i in `seq 0 10000`; do echo "insert into newtable (c1,c2) values($i,'bar$i');" >> ~/Downloads/foo.txt; done

rootuser@rootuser$ cp ~/Downloads/foo.txt ~/Downloads/foo.sql
```

upload the file foo.sql via workbench and hit run, it will generate 10K new rows